# Index non-NA values in R to subset a new data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
A <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "NA", "h", "I")
B <- c(NA, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, 5, 6, 8, NA)
C <- c(NA, 9, 8, 4, 5, 7, 5, 6, NA, NA)
D <- c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, 8, NA)
E <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E)
```

1). I would like to identify the position of the numerical values (non-NA values) in columns B, C, D to then create a new data frame based on the index of non-NAs.

My current code is:

```
s <- sapply(!is.na(df$B),  which)
```

Which works to give me a list of values denoting where the non-NA value is for only one of the columns. But I need to index 3 columns

```
s <- sapply(!is.na(df$B, df$C, df$D), 2, which)
```

This code gives me the error of Error in is.na(df$B, df$C, df$D) :
3 arguments passed to 'is.na' which requires 1

My expected output for indexing this df is:

```
    V1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    8
8    9
```

Any help in generating a code to get this output would be greatly appreciated!

2). I would then like to subset based on generating the above index and my expected output df2 would be:

```
A <- c("b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", NA, "h")
B <- c(2,3,4,NA, NA, 5,6, 8)
C <- c(9, 8, 4, 5, 7, 5, 6, NA)
D <- c(1,2,3,NA, 5, NA, 7, 8)
E <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

df2 <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E)
```

Any help in generating a code to get this second output would be greatly appreciated as I don't even know where to begin to write this code.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE`

```
which(!is.na(df[c("B", "C", "D")]), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

---

Using the OP's code, we may need to loop over the `matrix` by column

```
apply(!is.na(df[c("B", "C", "D")]), 2, which)
```

-output

```
$B
[1] 2 3 4 7 8 9

$C
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$D
[1] 2 3 4 6 8 9
```

---

If the intention is to `filter` with any non-NA value in the row for columns, B to D

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(if_any(B:D,  ~ !is.na(.)))
A  B  C  D E
1  b  2  9  1 2
2  c  3  8  2 3
3  d  4  4  3 4
4  e NA  5 NA 5
5  f NA  7  5 6
6  g  5  5 NA 7
7 NA  6  6  7 8
8  h  8 NA  8 9
```

Comment: Thank you for the above code.  The first code using which function is applicable for generating df2.  I figured out that df2 <- subset(df, (!is.na(df$B) | !is.na(df$C) | !is.na(df$D))) will generate the final data frame and I can bypass indexing first.

Comment: @vcat try the update